I want to cash in my 0.0249 ETH but it's saying insufficient funds?
I tried this via Transak on Metamask. Is there some minimum amount so I'm not allowed to get my money out? I hated giving them all my data to set this up too and then it didn't go through. I'm new and want out because it is all too complicated.

You may need to fill smaller than 0.0249. Your value should be = 0.0249 - estimate gas.

sorry, no idea what is Transak. But in general a small portion of your assets will go for transaction costs (so called gas fee). Usually this is calculated automatically. If it isn't, for some reason, you can try transfering 0.0248 (to reserve a bit for gas fees), for example. But there is no explicit minimum amount.
